# React Set Child State From Parent Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 js files. I want to change a state of Component2 from Component1.

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);          
        this.state = {
            enable: false
        };
        this.enable = React.createRef();
        this.selector = this.selector.bind(this);

    selector() {
        this.setState({
            enable: true,
        })
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <div>
                <select><option>ENABLE</option></select>
                <OtherComponent>
                    <Component2 enable={this.state.enable} />  
                </OtherComponent>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I want to set `enable: true` in Component2 via the `<option>`.

```
class Component2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            enable: false
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiverProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({ enable: nextProps.enable, })
    }

    render()
        return <div>{this.state.enable}</div>
```

I haven't tried this before with a nested Component structure in the render().

Comment: this should work, tho i don't think you need the ref and you may need to set it's initial state in a willMount or did Mount in component2. are you getting any errors?

Comment: You need to pass `selector()` function and `enable` from `Component1` to `Component2` as props and have an `onClick` event calling out that function to update the state of `enable` in parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use props to pass the data from the parent's state to the children (there's no need to bind states of parent and child, or use Refs, or attempt to involve life-cycle methods):

```js
const { render } = ReactDOM

class Component2 extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return (
          <div>
            Enabled: {this.props.isEnabled ? 'true' : 'false'}
          </div>
        )
    }
}

class OtherComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <div style={{backgroundColor:'black', color:'white', width:100}}>{this.props.children}</div>
  }
}

class Component1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.selector = this.selector.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            enable: false
        }
    }
        

    selector() {
        this.setState({
            enable: true
        })
    }

    render() {
        return ( 
            <div>
                <select onChange={this.selector}><option /><option>ENABLE</option></select>
                <OtherComponent>
                  <Component2 isEnabled={this.state.enable} />  
                </OtherComponent>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
    
render (
  <Component1 />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Great! This is what I want. I have a function in Component2 that checks if `enable: true`. Do I need to set isEnabled as a prop or something in Component2? And then use `if(isEnabled) {...` ?

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: You're most welcome and you should give a try to function components and hooks - your code base will appear much less verbose and I'm sure you're going to like it, there's really not that much class-based components bring to the table compared to function-based these days